# What happens to documents in documentDb that have no partition key property?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Looking at how to set up DocumentDb with a partition key, if I have a multi-tenant application, where most documents have a tenantId, it seems reasonable to create the collection with a partition key of /tenantId/.

What happens to documents that don't have a tenantId property? Will they just get added without one, or will Cosmos DB create those objects/documents with some kind of system (hard-coded) tenantId, so they are stored together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These documents are automatically assigned the "undefined" value for partition key (similar to JavaScript's undefined). This is treated like any other value, and all documents with missing keys are stored within the same partition. If you have a large number of these, then you would have trouble scaling as all writes within missing keys would get assigned to the same partition.

It's generally a good idea to avoid this, or fix this later by deleting/reinserting (if this lack of partition key is due to some asynchronous nature of not knowing the partition key at creation time).

Comment: I am going wit the above, where we assume the partition key will just be undefined, however when trying to delete a document that has no property related to the partition key I get the error "PartitionKey value must be supplied for this operation."? How do I delete these?

Comment: its seems one will need to add and delete documents passing in an undefined partition key:
requestOptions = new RequestOptions
                    {
                        PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(Undefined.Value)
                    };

Comment: yes, exactly. You should use Undefined.Value for partition key

Comment: Is there a difference in omitting partition key or using a dummy value (eg. guid.empty) for partition key if missing? But I guess it is harder to write queries that always include partition key (perf and RU) if it is missing:-)