# Azure Cosmos DB - Can I use a JSON field that doesn't exist for all documents as my partition key?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to setup a new Cosmos DB and it's asking me to set a partition key. I think I understand the concept where I should select a JSON field that can group my documents efficiently.

Is it possible to configure the collection to use a JSON field that may not exist in every incoming document?

For example:

```
{
    "name" : "Robin",
    "DOB" : "01/01/1969",
    "scans" : {
        "bloodType" : "O"
    }
}


{
    "name" : "Bill",
    "DOB" : "01/01/1969"
}
```

Can I use /scans.bloodType as the partion key? For documents that don't have a scans JSON field, I still want that data as I can update that document later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, indeed, specify a partition key that might not exist in every document. When you save a document that's missing the property specified by your partition key, it will result in assigning an "undefined" value for its partition key.

In the future, if you wanted to provide a value for the partition key of such a document, you'd have to delete, and then re-add, the document. You cannot modify a property's value when it happens to be the partition key within that document's container (nor can you *add* the property to an existing document that doesn't explicitly have that property defined, since it's already been assigned the "undefined" value).

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46624550/272109) for more details on undefined partition key properties.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do that.
As per the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview#choose-partitionkey) the partition key path (/scans.bloodType) or the partition key value cannot be changed.

> Be a property that has a value which does not change. If a property is your partition key, you can't update that property's value.

In terms of solutions, you could either try and find another partition Key property path and ensure there's a value at the time of creation, or maybe use a secondary collection to store your incomplete documents and use the change feed to "move" them to the final collection once all the data becomes available.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it seems like it is possible but the document would have to be completely removed and readded.

Answer (score 0):

Something like blood type wouldn't be a good partition key, assuming it refers to A/B/O types, etc, if there are only a small number of possible values. What you can generally always fall back on is the unique `id` property of the item, which Cosmos creates automatically. It's fine to have one item per partition, if nothing else is a better candidate. Per docs:

> If your container has a property that has a wide range of possible
> values, it is likely a great partition key choice. One possible
> example of such a property is the item ID. For small read-heavy
> containers or write-heavy containers of any size, the item ID is
> naturally a great choice for the partition key.

Comment: The issue here is that this doesn't answer the OP's question. They're not asking for advice on what to choose as partition key, nor about cardinality of partition key values. They're specifically asking if every document must have a property corresponding to the container's partition key, and whether the property could be added in a subsequent document update.

Comment: Good catch, David. Thanks for taking the time to point this out and downvote. I sometimes have the overzealous tendency to share additional information that seems like it might logically follow from a question, like "if I can't use this, what should I use instead". But indeed, OP didn't say that at all!

Comment: My point is that, as written, your answer addresses a different issue. An issue that could have been addressed in a (very valid and valuable) comment. But there's no way to correlate this answer, as an *answer*, to the original question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and comments from both of you! I appreciate it. 
But it does bring up another concern that I didn't realize - why wouldn't a field with a small range of values be a good partition key? I thought that was the point of partions - to organize the data for faster retrival? Or are you saying, partition keys need more value ranges? In Cosmos v3.6, Microsoft is recommending partiion keys now, you're not obligated to add a parition key but it SERIOUSLY helps out with the performance. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing